# Troubleshooting deployed assistant's missing responses

Tags: docker, nginx, socket.io, rasa

I've just deployed a (*veeery*) minimally viable virtual assistant ([explorer-ai.chat](https://explorer-ai.chat)) using Rasa Open-Source. It's currently running as a simple web app from a network of Docker containers built on an E2 machine (Ubuntu 18.04) hosted by Google Cloud.

Background that will help you interact with the chatbot: It's intended to function as a virtual docent to the [Exploratorium](https://www.exploratorium.edu/) in San Francisco. In particular, it should be able to answer basic questions that a human docent might be asked by a patron. The user intents fall into these categories:

- Get an explanation for a concept or phenomena which is illustrated by some exhibit at the Exploratorium
- Get information about a specific exhibit at the Exploratorium, identified by (common) name

  - Brief description
  - Current location (e.g. gallery)
  - Names of creator(s)
  - Year of creation
- Get exhibit recommendations

There are lots of issues with both NLU and dialog management that I'm working on fixing, but the purpose of *this* post is to understand behavior illustrated here:

[image: conversation snippet]

Specifically, the bot often fails to respond to a user utterance at some point in the conversation. Here are some items that might be relevant:

- This issue does not exist when I interact with the bot locally (un-Dockerized) using the `rasa shell` command. (However, I should mention that the models are different in the deployed and local versions -- when I Dockerized the application for deployment, any models that I `COPY`ed into the Docker container for the Rasa service were considered "invalid" (why?), so I decided to include a `RUN rasa train` statement in the Dockerfile. But since the models were trained on the same data and using the same configurations, I don't see how the difference would matter.)

Here's `docker-compose.yml` for the network:

```
version: '3'
services:

  rasa_server:
    container_name: "rasa_server"
    build:
      context: backend
    user: root
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    expose:
      - 5005

  action_server:
    container_name: "action_server"
    build:
      context: actions
    ports:
      - "5055:5055"
    expose:
      - 5055

  web_server:
    container_name: "web_server"
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - "rasa_server"
      - "action_server"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./web/conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./web/conf/explorer-ai.chat.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/explorer-ai.chat.conf
      - ./web/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./web/html:/var/www/html
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt

  certbot:
    container_name: "certbot"
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/cerbot:rw
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt:rw
```

`Dockerfile` for `backend`:

```
FROM rasa/rasa:3.3.1

WORKDIR /app

USER root

COPY ./models /app/models
COPY ./data /app/data
COPY . /app

RUN rasa train

ENTRYPOINT ["rasa", "run", "-m", "models", "--enable-api", "--cors", "*", "--debug"]
```

`Dockerfile` for `actions` (in case it's useful):

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.3.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements-actions.txt requirements.txt
COPY . /app

USER root

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

USER 1001

EXPOSE 5055

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "rasa_sdk", "--actions", "actions"]
```

- I'm using the socket.io endpoint behind (or is it in *front* of?) an Nginx reverse proxy.

My Rasa (backend) `credentials.yml` file includes

```
socketio:
  user_message_evt: user_uttered
  bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
  session_persistence: false
```

My `index.html` file contains:

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.2/socket.io.js"
  integrity="sha512-YybopSVjZU0fe8TY4YDuQbP5bhwpGBE/T6eBUEZ0usM72IWBfWrgVI13qfX4V2A/W7Hdqnm7PIOYOwP9YHnICw=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
<script>
  const socket = io("https://explorer-ai.chat");

  const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');

  function scrollToBottom() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }

  function appendMessage(msg, type) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.textContent = msg;
    item.classList.add("message");
    item.classList.add(`message_${type}`);
    messages.appendChild(item);
    scrollToBottom();
  }

  const welcome = "Hello! I'm Explorer AI, a virtual assistant for visitors to the " +
    "Exploratorium in San Francisco. I've been trained to answer questions about the " + 
    "Exploratorium's exhibits and the concepts they illustrate.";
  const how_help = "How may I assist you?";

  appendMessage(welcome, "received");
  appendMessage(how_help, "received");

  form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const msg = messageInput.value;
    if (msg) {
      socket.emit('user_uttered', {
        "message": msg,
      });
      messageInput.value = '';

      appendMessage(msg, "sent");
    }
  });

  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("Connected to Socket.io server");
  });

  socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
            
    console.log("Connection to Socket.io FAILED");
    console.error(error);
  });

  socket.on('bot_uttered', function (response) {
    console.log("Bot uttered:", response);
    if (response.text) {
      appendMessage(response.text, "received");
    }
    if (response.attachment) {
      appendImage(response.attachment.payload.src, "received");
    }
    if (response.quick_replies) {
      appendQuickReplies(response.quick_replies);
    }
  });

</script>
```

And here are my `web_server` configurations:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name explorer-ai.chat www.explorer-ai.chat;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://explorer-ai.chat$request_uri;
    }

} 

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name explorer-ai.chat www.explorer-ai.chat;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/explorer-ai.chat/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/explorer-ai.chat/privkey.pem;
    include                 /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam             /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://rasa_server:5005;

    }

}
```

- In order to test the app locally (on `localhost`), I have to make slight changes to the Docker configurations in order to accommodate my M1 chip. In particular, my `backend` service is build `FROM khalosa/rasa-aarch64:3.3.1`. In this setting, I notice that the bot tends to (almost?) always ignore the first user utterance. The logs below are from such a local test.

Here is a section of the log corresponding to the very beginning of the conversation above:

[image: log snippet #1]

It seems that the correct action is predicted and a `BotUttered` event was triggered. But there's no action from the web server during this time. (Also, why do all of the logged events have the same timestamp?) In fact, the next log entries from the web server are these, which occur *before* the user's next message.

[image: log snippet #2]

Am I right in thinking this has something to do with the networking (Nginx, socket.io), and not the Rasa components?

Thanks so much for reading, and for any help you can provide! In case it's not obvious, I'm a noob. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't have the proxy configured correctly. The `/socket.io/` location needed some additional directives. This ended up working:

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass          http://rasa_server:5005;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

and, in order to avoid an `unknown "connection_upgrade" variable` error, I also needed to add the following directive to the `http` block my `nginx.conf` file:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {  
    default   upgrade;
    ''        close;
}
```

I think that, previously, the proxy connection was falling back to HTTP long polling (the default for socket.io).